# How to find class instances by contents of attr array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, search

```
class Dresser
  @@all = []
  attr_accessor :name, :height, :length, :width, :contents
  def initialize (name, height,length, width)
    @name = name
    @height = height
    @length = length
    @width = width
    @contents = []
    @@all << self
  end

  def Dresser.all
    @@all
  end

  def add_content(content)
    @contents << content
  end
end

a = Dresser.new('a', 4, 6, 8)
a.add_content('sock')
a.add_content('hat')
b = Dresser.new('b', 3, 6, 9)
b.add_content('bra')
c = Dresser.new('c', 4, 7, 6)
c.add_content('hat')
```

How would I go about searching through @@all for the name of dressers that contain a specific item, say a hat? 
Edit: Realized the code I initially entered was incorrect.  Whoops!

Comment: This can be solved in the same manner as with looking through *any* array.. Maybe start with solving something "less convoluted" to understand the process: *Write code to find the arrays in the following array that contain the number 2*: `[ [1,2,3], [1], [], [2] ]`. The result should be `[ [1,2,3], [2] ]`. In solving that, the problem asked here (and buried in very specific situation) will be solved: the outer array is '@@all' and each nested array is '@contents' of the specific instance.

Comment: Using a class instance variable like `@@all` can get you into trouble, so be careful when doing this.

Comment: I understand how to find specific arrays in a nested array and I know how to search for instances by their attributes, like height or name in this case. I just haven't figured out how to find class instances by the contents of an array that is attributed to them. The best I have been able to do is to find and return the specific array itself, but without any reference to the instance it belongs to, which is the issue.  So I can find the arrays that contain 'hat' and return to me the arrays themselves, but I have no idea which dressers they came from.

Comment: Dresser.all.each{|d| puts d.contents.select{|c| c.include? 'hat'}}

This is the best I have been able to come up with, but like I said, it fails to tell me which dressers.  It just finds the hats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reader `contents` method then call `select`.

```
class Dresser

#rest of your code

  def contents
    @contents
  end
end

#Assuming your instance additions
Dresser.all.select {|d| d.contents.include? 'hat'}
=>
[#<Dresser:0x000000020b0890 @name="a", @height=4, @length=6, @width=8, @contents=["sock", "hat"]>,
 #<Dresser:0x000000020b0728 @name="c", @height=4, @length=7, @width=6, @contents=["hat"]>]
```

Comment: Wow, I had tried exactly and was only missing the reader method.  Derp.  Thanks.  I was very confused why it wasn't working and didn't realize I was missing a simple fundamental.